# Dog mounting. Help

Tags: dogs, behavior, introducing-pets, neutering

I currently have 2 dogs, a 9 month old female collie and a 20 month old Chihuahua/jack Russell male who's neutered. We are fostering a 17 month old intact Siberian husky but seem to be having some issues.

He is constantly trying to mount my little chihuahua/jack Russell and nibbling at his fur on his back. Would getting him neutered help this at all?

Comment: he's still a puppy, so a lot of it is play, but definitely neutering will help calm his behaviour.

Comment: Can you describe the 'nibbling'?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that this could be really.

1, Establishing himself in the pack, mounting and humping are often a way of displaying dominance to other dogs, regardless of size.

2, The nibbling could be play and trying to engage the other dog in to playing with them.

Neutering could solve the problem, however one risk of this is that the dog could potentially go the opposite way and become MORE like this. Its best to channel the behaviour into something else. A distraction.

When he starts, quickly distract him by telling him to get off and instead give him something else to do, he's still fairly young so play is the best way. Play tug or fetch etc, or do some basic training in obedience so he will work for you.